# Regex capture optional group in any order

Tags: regex, ruby

I would like to capture groups based on a consecutive occurrence of matched groups in any order. And when one set type is repeated without the alternative set type, the alternative set is returned as nil.

So the following:

```
"123 dog cat cow 456 678 890 sheep"
```

Would return the following:

```
[["123", "dog"], [nil, "cat"], ["456", "cow"], ["678", nil], ["890", sheep]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Sounds more like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. What is _the task itself_? Why do you think regexp is the solution?

Comment: If my understanding is correct I find this to be an interesting question. Considering that it’s already attracted downvotes, however, you need to work harder in providing a precise and unambiguous statement of the problem. The example is essential but it would be better if you explained how the return value was obtained (e.g., “The first two words, “123” and “dog” are examined. As the first is comprised of digits only and the second is comprised of non-digits only,...Then the next two words, “cat” and “cow”, are considered. Since neither word is all digits, ... As “cow” was not part of the...

Comment: ...previously-saved two-element array, the next two words considered are “cow” and “456”....”. Two details: 1) can we assume that each word is all digits or all non-digits? 2) what if only a single word is left at the end?

Comment: Are you only interested in solutions that employ a singular regular expression or would you like to see other approaches to solving the problem? (I believe that's what @Konstantin had in mind when referring to “XY problems”.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland to me this example looks like parsing of some non-regular language, so regexp won't do the job by definition. But this is just a raw guess - it is really hard to say for sure without the proper problem definition (and more corner cases, probably - for example, how should smth. like "cat cat cat cat" be parsed)?

Comment: @Konstantin, I assume that should be `[[nil,'cat'],[nil,'cat'],[nil,'cat'],[nil,'cat']]`. My understanding of the question is embodied by my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are correct. I've updated the question to answer any ambiguities in my initial submission. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit changed the question by replacing strings of digits with strings containing one or more words and replacing single words with email addresses. That's a definite no-no at SO, for obvious reasons: it can render existing answers incorrect or even nonsensical, as it did here. You can of course ask a separate question. Note that when you edit questions (or answers), there is no need for an "Update" notification.

Comment: I'll add it as a separate question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression can get us part of the way, but I do not believe all the way.

```
r = /
    (?:        # begin non-capture group
      \d+      # match 1+ digits
      [ ]      # match 1 space
      [^ \d]+  # match 1+ chars other than digits and spaces
      |        # or
      [^ \d]+  # match 1+ chars other than digits and spaces
      [ ]      # match 1 space
      \d+      # match 1+ digits
      |        # or
      [^ ]+    # match 1+ chars other than spaces
    )          # end non-capture group
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
str = "123 dog cat cow 456 678 890 sheep"
```

```
str.scan(r).map do |s|
  case s
  when /\d [^ \d]/
    s.split(' ')
  when /[^ \d] \d/
    s.split(' ').reverse
  when /\d/
    [s,nil]
  else
    [nil,s]
  end
end
  #=> [["123", "dog"], [nil, "cat"], ["456", "cow"],
  #    ["678", nil], ["890", "sheep"]]
```

Note:

```
str.scan r
  #=> ["123 dog", "cat", "cow 456", "678", "890 sheep"]
```

This regular expression is conventionally written

```
/(?:\d+ [^ \d]+|[^ \d]+ \d+|[^ ]+)/
```

---

Here is another solution that only uses regular expressions incidentally.

```
def doit(str)
  str.gsub(/[^ ]+/).with_object([]) do |s,a|
    prev = a.empty? ? [0,'a'] : a.last
    case s
    when /\A\d+\z/ # all digits
      if prev[0].nil?
        a[-1][0] = s
      else
        a << [s,nil]
      end
    when /\A\D+\z/ # all non-digits
      if prev[1].nil?
        a[-1][1] = s
      else
        a << [nil,s]
      end
    else
      raise ArgumentError
    end
  end
end
```

```
doit str
  #=> [["123", "dog"], [nil, "cat"], ["456", "cow"], ["678", nil],
  #    ["890", "sheep"]]
```

This uses of the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that has no block and therefore returns an enumerator:

```
enum = str.gsub(/[^ ]+/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "123 dog cat cow 456 678 890 sheep":gsub(/[^ ]+/)> 
enum.next
  #=> "123" 
enum.next
  #=> "dog"
...
enum.next
  #=> "sheep" 
enum.next
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```